# How to specify regex replacement for different capturing groups in F#

Tags: regex, f#

I'm writing a md2html compiler in F# and I want to replace the `**` surrounding texts with `<b>` and `</b>` tags.

e.g.
`this is **bold**` will be changed to `this is <b>bold</b>`

I am trying to accomplish this with `Regex.Replace` method using the pattern `(\*\*).*?(\*\*)`. So the first capturing group will be replaced by `<b>` and the second one will be replaced by `</b>` I would like to know how I can specify the replacement for these different "capturing groups" rather than the entire regex match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should capture what you need to keep. You need to just match what you need to replace.

Use `\*\*(.*?)\*\*` pattern and `<b>$1</b>` replacement.

If you expect line breaks in between asterisks, use a singleline modifier `(?s)`:  `(?s)\*\*(.*?)\*\*`

Answer (score 5):

Just use this regex: [`\*\*(.*?)\*\*`](https://regex101.com/r/ZchGZj/2) and replace the matches with `<b>$1</b>`

#### Explanation:

- `\*\*` matches `**` literally.
- `(` starts a capture group.
- `.*` just matches everything it can get that isn't a new line.
- `?` this makes the `.*` lazy, so that it doesn't match other bold text.
- `)` ends the capture group.
- `\*\*` matches `**` literally.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this is to capture the inner group instead of the surrounding `**` and then use it in the replacement.

```
Regex.Replace("this is **bold**", "\*\*(.*?)\*\*", "<b>$1</b>")
```

`Regex.Replace` doesn't replace captured groups, but the whole match.